# String.Format double with no separator

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

I have some double values for example:

```
24.1
0.5
9.0
```

I want to format those values so that I get the number before the dot and three digits after the dot. This number should not be separated by a dot
so it would end up like this:

```
24100
0500
9000
```

My current solution, which I dislike looks like this:

```
public override String ToString()
{
    String formatparameter  = "{0:0.000}";
    String stringFix = String.Format(formatparameter, m_Fix);
    stringFix = stringFix.Replace(".", "");
    stringFix =stringFix.Replace(",", "");
    return stringFix
}
```

Is there a String.Format "formatParameter" which makes the string.Replace redundant/obsolete ?

**EDIT:**

For clarification I am looking for a format parameter. The solutions provided until now are great in regards of their output but I hope to find a parameter.

Comment: Can't you just multiply it by 1000?

Comment: and 500 is the same value (numerically) as 0500.  It's just a question of formatting it - see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TkzSmj) or one of the similar answers.

Comment: Be sure to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, you can leave out the "," replacement with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
return string.Format("{0}{1:000}", (int)m_Fix, (m_Fix*1000)%1000);
```

or with C# 6

```
return $"{(int)m_Fix}{(m_Fix*1000)%1000:000}"
```

Test with your three values and got this output:

```
24100
0500
9000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes it is correct if you look at the output, but I am looking for a "formatParameter".

Comment: @Bongo I don't think there is a format parameter that ommits the decimal point.

Comment: I will leave this question open for several hours. If you are right I will check this as the correct answer because it is the most correct one and it was first

Answer (score 4):

**Updated**
Here's what I'd do:

```
public static String ToString(double d)
{
    return (d * 1000.0).ToString("0000");
}

Console.WriteLine(ToString(24.1));
Console.WriteLine(ToString(0.5));
Console.WriteLine(ToString(9.0));
```

Output:

```
24100
0500
9000
```

Comment: Your first answer was correct, it just had one to many zero's in the format, much clearer than what you've updated it to.